# Recursive convert values to string using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python

Using *dictionary comprehension* is it possible to convert all values ***recursively*** to string?

I have this dictionary

```
d = {
  "root": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

I tried

```
{k: str(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

But the code above turns the entire `root` value into string and I want this:

```
d = {"root": {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"}}
```

Comment: I hope you know, `"root": {
    "a", "1",
    "b", 2,
    "c", 3,
    "d", 4,
  }`root's  value is not a dictionary.=]

Comment: The question doesn't make sense if it's not a dictionary, since sets are not ordered

Comment: You right. Just fixed the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a dictionary comprehension, but it works, it's just one line, and it's recursive!

```
(f := lambda d: {k: f(v) for k, v in d.items()} if type(d) == dict else str(d))(d)
```

It only works with Python 3.8+ though (because of the use of an assignment expression).

Answer (score 2):

You could do a recursive solution for arbitrarily nested dicts, but if you only have 2 levels the following is sufficient:

```
{k: {k2: str(v2) for k2, v2 in v.items()} for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: @Rodrigo You don't get this error if the inner dictionary is actually a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your given input was wrong and `root's` value was a dictionary, your code would somewhat work. You just need to add `d['root'].items()`

```
newDict = {k:{k: str(v) for k, v in d[k].items()} for k,v in d.items()}
```

output

```
{'root': {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'}}
```

Comment: The key `root` was a example, could be anything

Answer (score 0):

The following solution might not be using dictionary comprehension, but it is recursive and can transform dictionaries of any depth, I don't think that's possible using comprehension alone:

```py
def convert_to_string(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            convert_to_string(value)
        else:
            d[key] = str(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler way to to achieve this using `json` module. Just made the following

```
import json


string_json = json.dumps(d) # Convert to json string
d = json.loads(string_json, parse_int=str) # This convert the `int` to `str` recursively.
```

Using a function

```
def dictionary_string(dictionary: dict) -> dict:
    return json.loads(json.dumps(dictionary), parse_int=str, parse_float=str)
```

Regards